# Weblogic 12.1.3 & JSF 2.1.7 deploying (jsf.spi.injection.provider_not_implemented)

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2, weblogic12c

I am trying to upgrade our Weblogic domain from 12.1.2 to 12.1.3, but when I try to deploy 12.1.3, I get this error:

```
<jsf.spi.injection.provider_not_implemented> <JSF1029: The specified InjectionProvider implementation 'com.bea.faces.WeblogicInjectionProvider' does not implement the InjectionProvider interface. >
```

That error is not clear for me.

My `weblogic.xml` is:

```
  <wls:prefer-application-packages> 
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name> 
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.hql.ast.*</wls:package-name>                     
        <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name> 
        <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>             
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>    
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>             
    </wls:prefer-application-packages> 

<wls:prefer-application-resources>  
        <wls:resource-name>javax.faces.*</wls:resource-name>  
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>  
        <wls:resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:resource-name>  

        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name> 
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
```

Environment:

- Hibernate 4.3.8
- JPA 2.1 (i have pached Interim Patch for Bug: 20087183)
- Mojorra 2.1.7

Comment: arent any one in oracle answer this or they dont know how to fix it?